# Print last Sunday of each month in a given year

Tags: datetime, ocaml

I'm an experienced programmer trying to learn OCaml. I figured a good way to do that would be to pick a simple task on Rosetta code that didn't yet have an OCaml example and do it myself. With that in mind, I wrote this program to [find the last sunday of each month in a given year.](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_the_last_Sunday_of_each_month) It works by using Gauss's algorithm to determine what day of the week the last day in each month of the year is and if it's not a Sunday it moves backwards until it is. I run it with "./ocaml sundays.ml N" where N is the year in question. Are there any spots where my code is written in a way unusual for OCaml developers or where there is a more OCamlish way of doing things?

```
let is_leap_year y =
  (* See OCaml solution on Rosetta Code for 
     determing if it's a leap year *) 
   if (y mod 100) = 0
     then (y mod 400) = 0
     else (y mod 4) = 0;;

let get_days aYear =
  if is_leap_year aYear
    then
      [31;29;31;30;31;30;31;31;30;31;30;31]
    else
      [31;28;31;30;31;30;31;31;30;31;30;31];;

let print_date y m d =
  print_int y;
  print_char '/';
  print_int m;
  print_char '/';
  print_int d;
  print_endline "";;

let get_day_of_week y m d =
  let y = if m > 2 then y else y - 1 in
  let c = y / 100 in
  let y = y mod 100 in
  let m_shifted = float_of_int ( ((m + 9) mod 12) + 1) in
  let m_factor = int_of_float (2.6 *. m_shifted -. 0.2) in
  let leap_factor = 5 * (y mod 4) + 3 * (y mod 7) + 5 * (c mod 4) in
  (d + m_factor + leap_factor) mod 7;; 

let get_shift y m last_day =
  get_day_of_week y m last_day;;

let print_last_sunday y m =
  let days = get_days y in
  let last_day = List.nth days (m - 1) in
  let last_sunday = last_day - (get_shift  y m last_day) in
  print_date y m last_sunday;;

let print_last_sundays y =
  let months = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12] in
  List.iter (print_last_sunday y) months;;

match (Array.length Sys.argv ) with 
  2 -> print_last_sundays( int_of_string (Sys.argv.(1)));
 |_ -> invalid_arg "Please enter a year";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You do not need to put `;;` everywhere. They're artifact of the interpreter.
2. `print_date` can be rewritten using `printf`:

   ```
   let print_date = Printf.printf "%d/%d/%d"
   ```
3. It is better to store days in an array. List is not a good container for random access. Also, syntactically it would be easier to read: `days.(2)` is better than `List.nth 2`. Also, just FYI, you can have arrays in OCaml indexed from one, e.g., `let days = Bigarray.(Array1.create int fortran_layout 12)`. Although, using them here would be overkill, I think.
4. You do not need parens here:

   ```
   let last_sunday = last_day - (get_shift  y m last_day) in
   ```